# Github PR templates don't work in enterprise git?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

GitHub released this nice feature to create PR templates[1]. Me and my team wanted to leverage that. However,I couldn't get it to work in enterprise git.

Is the new feature not available in GitHub Enterprise yet?

[1]https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pull request template feature is not available in GitHub Enterprise as of March 12, 2016. The latest releases of GitHub Enterprise are 2.5.1, 2.4.5, 2.3.9, 2.2.15, and 2.1.20. Features introduced at GitHub.com may make their way into GitHub Enterprise, but it is not guaranteed. For instance, Jupiter notebook support was added to GitHub.com on May 7, 2015, but has not yet made its way into GitHub Enterprise.

GitHub Enterprise release notes can be found [here](https://enterprise.github.com/releases/)